# Using argv to read a text file

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, argv, argc

I am trying to read a text file using argv[1]. In my code after building argc remains 1 only that means the file is not detected. Please see my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char msg[256]={0};
    if (argc < 2){
        cout<<"file not found";
    }
    if(argc > 1){
        strcpy(msg,argv[1]);
    }
     FILE *file;
     if ((file = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
         {
             printf("file doesnt exist\n");
         }
     fclose(file);

    cout<<argv[1];

}
```

I am not able to figure out how do I get the value of argc greater than 1 and then read the content of the file?

Comment: What is the command you used to run the program? ie `myexe.exe ????`

Comment: Pass arguments to get the value of argc greater than 1. How to do it will depend on your shell or IDE that you use to run your program.

Comment: You shouldn't use `msg` like this because `argv[1]` can be used directly and this copying allows buffer overrun.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am trying to run it in eclipse and I set an argument in 'Run-configurations' but still it does not detect the file to read.

Comment: @MikeCATI I passed an argument but it still does not detect the text file..and I have changed the msg to argv[1]

Comment: Try creating a file in the current directory from your code. Perhaps the IDE is playing with the current directory and your running from a different folder than your text file.

Comment: No I created a file in the same directory where the source code is. I tried creating a file using the code and try reading it, but it didnt work as well.
I am confused whether what exactly should be the argument. Should it be just file name  of complete path?

Answer (score 0):

> argc remains 1 only that means the file is not detected

If argc is 1, that means no (command line) arguments were given to the program. I suggest that you change the response message to reflect that.

> how do I get the value of argc greater than 1

You need to pass an argument to the program. On the command line, you do it like this:

```
> ./program_file_name value_of_first_argument
```

If you launch the program from an IDE, then look up the IDE manual for how to set command line arguments for the launch.

---

Note that if the argument is longer than 256 characters in your program, then your buffer overflows and the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I am using eclipse and in the run configurations I have set the working directory to be where my file exists and in arguments I have specified the file name. The output comes out to be the filename which I have specified in the arguments. Is there a specific way to do it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

have you try drag and drop your file to your application? that should give you argv[1], if drag and drop did not work (which it should have worked), then something goes wrong

or try to use FULL PATH, you don't really need to copy argv[1], just use it directly...

Comment: I tried out drag and drop but it doesnt seem to work..By FULL PATH do you mean to use it as argument or just the file name as argument?

Comment: if it didn't work, something goes wrong, i suggest to cout all of the argument : 
for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
      cout<<argv[i]<<endl;

did it show full path of the file?

Comment: if your cout show the correct path for your file, but is NULL inf FILE*file, then your file is probably opened by other aplication.

Comment: Actually when I do it using command line I get the desired result(reading the file using argv). i am confused what exactly should I specify in the arguments in Run Configurations in Eclipse. I tried by providing "file.txt" in the argument but I dont get the desired result.